# What is the origin of this triplet: Time, Talents, and Treasure?

Tags: terminology, language

I am 50 years old, and I just became aware of widespread usage of "Time, Talents, and Treasure" in religious circles, maybe especially Catholicism. My own religion, Mormonism, has a temple covenant about consecrating time, talents, and "everything with which the Lord has blessed you, or with which he may bless you" to the LDS church. And I was not aware until recently that it might be a conscious deviation from an old triplet.

Does anybody know from where the pithier version originates? My completely uniformed guess would be that it might have originated in some sort of Catholic catechism or papal pronouncement.